# When a SensorEvent is reused by the system, does it allocate a new values array?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm using android sensors, and I don't want my code to produce a new object for each sensor event. For now, I'm copying the values contained in the array `SensorEvent.values` to my own `Sample` class values array.

I know `SensorEvent`s are reused by the system and cannot be kept, but **I was wondering if `SensorEvent.values` was also reused or if a new array was allocated**. Indeed, there is no point in copying the array into mine if a new is created anyway (I'd better replace my own array by `SensorEvent.values` directly).

I've been looking at different posts like [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691378/arraylistsensorevent-add-begins-overwriting-values) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164107/how-to-make-a-copy-of-the-android-sensor-sensorevent-object) but they deal with `SensorEvent` objects and not the `values` field itself.

Comment: Same thing for event.values as described in the links.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;) Though I don't see where you could see it in the links. They talk about the reference to the `SensorEvent` that shouldn't be kept, because this object could change. However they don't say whether `event.value` pointer will remain constant (but pointing to changing values).

Comment: No it is not constant. You can see by setting your variable equal to event.values. You will get weird value once every say 5 returns.

Comment: You're right I just did this experiment (should have done this in the first place, sorry for having asked a question for this). 
So it means that `event.values` is actually the same pointer (kept in `SensorEvent`) and only the values are changed, not the reference. Therefore, I can't use `event.values` directly and I should keep copying the values of the array into mine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify for future readers, the array `SensorEvent.values` is reused as well as the `SensorEvent` object. Therefore, one should not keep any reference to it, and should instead copy each value.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r1/core/java/android/hardware/SensorEvent.java), it is declared as

```
public final float[] values;
```

So the array is not reallocated, it is just reused -- you'll have to clone it.